# Attainment of the maximum in the induced norm definition

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

I am not looking for an answer, but rather a hint for the following question:
The induced norm $||A||_{a,b}\,$ is defined as
$||A||_{a,b} = \max\{||Ax||_b : ||x||_a ≤ 1\}$.
Prove that there exists an $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $||x||_a ≤ 1$ and $||A||_{a,b} = ||Ax||_b$.
Hint: Prove that the norm function is continuous and use the extreme value theorem.

I am just really confused on how to begin proving this and was wondering if someone could give me a hint! really just trying to get unstuck.

Comment: proving continuity *is* the major hint here. Also prove boundedness of the set $\{x: \|x\|_a\le1}$.

Comment: @mathhelp Are you saying that you're having trouble proving that the norm function is continuous?

Comment: I am having trouble proving the norm function is continuous! @BenGrossmann I do not know where to begin with this proof

Comment: @mathhelp420 Understood. Do you have a definition of "continuous" that you are using in this context? I'm wondering whether your definition of continuity of a function $f:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ has anything to do with the norm $\|\cdot\|_a$ in this case. All "reasonable" definitions of continuity are equivalent here, but which definition we use affects the structure of the proof